# Qt5.12 minimize/maximize Application window breaks anchoring

Tags: qt, qml

I've faced with a very strange behaviour for ApplicationWindow. Here is my code :

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

ApplicationWindow {
   visible: true
   width: 640
   height: 480
   title: qsTr("App test")

   Rectangle {
      width : parent.width/2
      height : parent.height/2
      anchors.centerIn: parent
      color : "red"
   }
}
```

I press maximize window button, then minimize and see the following picture:
[image]

Then again maximize and minimize and things seems to get worse :
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Run well on Ubuntu/qt 5.12. That probably some graphics driver issue, the windows doesn't update. Try to replace `ApplicationWindow` with `Window`, set `QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);` or `AA_UseDesktopOpenGL` flag instead.

Comment: Already gave it a try but that didn't help :(. I'm running Ubuntu 18.10.

Comment: Tried with qmlscene, Linux Mint 18.3, Qt 5.12 and nvidia 410 drivers. Works fine. Must be a driver glitch.